# Linq Combine Left Join Data

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have the following database:

```
Users
-------
UserId (PK)
UserName

Roles
-----
RoleId (PK)
RoleName

UserRoles
---------
UserId (PK)
RoleId (PK)
```

Users 1-M UserRoles M-1 Roles

Using LinqToSQL, I want to return the following set:

```
[User1], [Role1, Role2, Role3]
[User2], [Role2, Role3]
[User3], []
```

Etc...

What is the most efficient way to create this LinqToSql Query?

In addition, if I want to create a filter to return only users that have Role1, what would that entail?

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define "efficient". But otherwise...

```
from u in dataContext.Users
select new { User = u, Roles = u.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role) }
```

And filtering users by `RoleID`:

```
from u in dataContext.Users
where u.UserRoles.Any(ur => ur.RoleID == 1)
select u
```

Or by some other `Role` attribute, say, `Name`:

```
from u in dataContext.Users
where u.UserRoles.Any(ur => ur.Role.Name == "Role 1")
select u
```

Combining it all together:

```
from u in dataContext.Users
select new
{
     User = u,
     Roles = from ur in u.UserRoles
             where ur.RoleID == 1 || ur.Role.Name == "Role 1"
             select ur.Role
}
```

Comment: I'm by no means familiar with LINQ to SQL but I'm not convinced this is correct.  Wouldn't `u.UserRoles` suggest that `UserRoles` is a field on the User table?

Comment: Not at all. L2S automatically creates collection-type "navigation properties" when another table references this table via foreign key. So long as `UserRole` table has `UserID` set as FK to `User` table, the entity class generated for `User` will have a property named `UserRoles`.

Comment: How would i filter by role id?

Comment: I take it I can combine both "queries" into one?

Comment: You mean you want to use the first query, but also filter? Yes, you can, though in that case you'd want to replace `.Any()` with `.Where()`, inserting it before `.Select()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the single query that I would construct to get your desired result set all at once

```
from u in Users
join ur in UserRoles on u.UserId equals ur.UserId
join r in Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.RoleId
group r by u into grouping
select grouping
```

It produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[UserId], [t0].[Username]
FROM [Users] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [UserRoles] AS [t1] ON [t0].[UserId] = [t1].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [Roles] AS [t2] ON [t1].[RoleId] = [t2].[RoleId]
GROUP BY [t0].[UserID], [t0].[Username]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 Int = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[RoleId], [t2].[RoleName]
FROM [Users] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [UserRoles] AS [t1] ON [t0].[UserId] = [t1].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [Roles] AS [t2] ON [t1].[RoleId] = [t2].[RoleId]
WHERE @x1 = [t0].[UserId]
```

[@Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488414/linq-combine-left-join-data/1488444#1488444)'s looks like it produces a better SQL statement:

```
SELECT [t0].[UserId], [t0].[Username], [t2].[RoleId], [t2].[RoleName] (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [UserRoles] AS [t3]
    INNER JOIN [Roles] AS [t4] ON [t4].[RoleId] = [t3].[RoleId]
    WHERE [t3].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [Users] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN ([UserRoles] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [Roles] AS [t2] ON [t2].[RoleId] = [t1].[RoleId]) ON [t1].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId]
ORDER BY [t0].[UserId], [t1].[UserRoleId], [t2].[RoleId]
```

In terms of efficient, testing is going to be the best way to figure out what most performant approach is for your situation.

Comment: is there a way to get rid of sub query in Pavel's query? thanks